# Pairing to a Bluetooth Low Energy device in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to automatically connect to Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices?

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) indicates that the [`BluetoothDevice.connectGatt()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context, boolean, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback)) has a autoConnect parameter:

> boolean indicating whether to automatically connect to the BLE device
>   as soon as it becomes available

However, to call this, you need a `BluetoothDevice` first. AFAIK the only way to get this is by scanning available devices. Setting up a scan every time to connect to a device doesn't seem like a desirable way. Also, I tried using [nRF Control Master Panel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) to connect to my peripheral using the `autoConnect = true`, but this does not connect to the device. Connecting without the `autoConnect` however does make it connect, and I've managed to read and write data from and to my peripheral this way with success.

The general way in Bluetooth to have two devices paired. However, searching for my BLE device and using [`BluetoothDevice.createBond()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond()) does not seem to work. In my `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED`-callback, the `EXTRA_BOND_STATE` and `EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE` just go from `BOND_BONDING` to `BOND_NONE` and back. I don't read out an error or anything - so maybe I'm missing something here. Here's the callback:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {

            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
            final int prevState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            Log.e(TAG, "prevState " + prevState + ", state " + state);
        }
    }
};
```

So this type of bonding does not seem to work.

My question is: am I doing something wrong for pairing or the autoConnect? Or is how I currently have it working the only correct way? It seems like a real pain (and battery-drain) to have to scan for devices every time, see if the device is there, if so read data and check back tomorrow, otherwise check back in an hour or so. The point of Bluetooth is that it should pair directly whenever it is near, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work without rescan. You do not need pairing at all. Just call `BluetoothGatt.connect()` again for gatt object you aquired from first connection.
You will receive `onConnectionStateChange` event in your `BluetoothGattCallback` as soon as ble device will be available again. If you use autoconnect option, you don't even need to call  `BluetoothGatt.connect()` method. Just monitor your cllback, and don't forget to close BluetoothGatt with `close()` if you don't see any connection for too long.

And yes, to obtain first connection you should scan for ble devices with `BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan`, not the common bluetooth devices scan.

Comment: So every time the app starts up, the first time I have to scan for it? Doesn't seem like a very user-friendly method as opposed to pairing devices.

Comment: yes, Android ble stack isn't user-friendly at all)))) All async, rescan on every startup, etc... You can try to keep all up in sticky service, but if it will be closed - you'll need ble rescan.

Comment: Ok thanks, thought I was missing something because I thought BLE would be massively supported...

Comment: the good side is that all rescan-reconecting is going without any negotiations with user, not like common bluetooth pairing.

Comment: True, but pairing was only once, now you still need to store the address of the BLE device to know to which you have to connect automagically

Comment: Raiv are you saying that after I do the initial connection (autoconnect = false) when I get a disconnect indication just call BluetoothGatt.connect() and when the device comes alive, I will connect to it? If so, that means the Android is scanning in the background looking for an advertisement with the right BT address. How long will that keep going? What happens if I do the same procedure for two devices?

Comment: Hmm. It should go until you call disconnect. I never tried to connect to two devices at once, but I suppose the behaviour will be the same, just keep track about which gatt device reports to you in `BluetoothGattCallback` Moreover, if you select `autoconnect=true` in initial connection, device should reconnect automtically without calling to `connect` again.